# Limit User Permissions to Add and View Only

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions, designer-workflow

Is there a way to limit a user to only be able to Add a new item to a list. I know that the user must have at least list permissions of Contribute in order to start a workflow, but I don't like that it gives them the ability to go in and edit if they have access to the list.

Any thoughts or workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default,** workflow only has a write permission, The user has no permissions.

So it's necessary to add your action at **`App Step`** to elevate the required permissions!

[image]

**How it works**

- It allows the application to authorize by using only its identity and
  ignoring that of the user.
- it grants full control permission to the workflow.

**For more details check**

- [The workflow was suspended with unauthorized HTTP / elevate workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)
- [Create a workflow with elevated permissions by using the SharePoint Workflow platform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-workflo)

Comment: Be aware that if you grant Full Control this way it means that every workflow within the site collection could use this. So if you do not control who can create workflows you possibly grant permissions to users you do not want to grant such permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the input, HappySPUser. That brings up another question. So if I have activated the App Step for the site, does the user still have to have contribute permissions in order to start a workflow? I'm kind of confused as to what it has full control over. Is it only the actions contained within the app step, or the entire workflow?

Comment: @M.Qassas Please see the update and image I posted above. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try to add the SharePoint 2010 workflow actions in Impersonation Step in your first workflow, then in SP 2013 workflow, try to remove the start workflow action from the App step, I would also try this in my side and feedback you ASAS,

Comment: Wouldn't that eliminate the purpose of the App Step altogether if am removing the action from the 2013 workflow? When I removed the action from my workflow originally, the 2010 workflow ran and completed when the list item was created because the user had "Contribute" permissions to the list. I have the outcome assigned to a variable, which updates the current list item. So, how would using the impersonation step and not using the app step work better? Just wondering...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66218/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-limit-user-permissions-to-add-and-view-only).